# create vm with GUI in Hyper-V powershell

Tags: command-line, powershell, hyper-v, windows-server-2019

I have a physical server installed with Windows Nano Server 2019. I have installed the Hyper-V role on it. Is it possible to create a VM with a GUI in powershell? I have googled quite a bit, but can't really find an answer.

Comment: Can you run the Hyper-V Manager (Look in All Apps). If you can you should be able to create a VM.  Use the Virtual Machine installer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @John I don't have access to the machine right now. Besides, I don't thin I've that option since it's a Nano Server